# Java JTextArea & JScrollPane not working

Tags: java, jscrollpane, jtextarea

i am writing simple code with GUI that should have one text area which should be scrollable. So far so good. 
I created my frame and the text area and i can write in it ok. Next I created my ScrollPane and added the TextArea in it, then added the ScrollPane to the frame but nothing shows. 
Here is the code i have at this point:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 325, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    //textArea
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEnabled(true);
    textArea.setEditable(true);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    textArea.setBounds(10, 101, 272, 149);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
```

Comment: dont use null layout... use a layout manager like BorderLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the bounds to the component that is being added to the content pane of the frame. In this case, it should be: `scroll.setBounds(10,101,271,149)`.

However, I strongly recommend to not use `null layout`. Use a layout manager of your choice, `BorderLayout` for instance. In this case you don't have to worry about the bounds, it will fit the frame size (it will resize when you change the size of the frame). Here's your example, tweaked a little bit:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 325, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // textArea
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEnabled(true);
        textArea.setEditable(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the answer - setBounds to the scroll. Thank you good sir. However with null Layout it looks ok :) with BorderLayout it is ok too, but one of my Jlabels dissapears XD

Comment: When you use a layout manager you should specify where you want to put the components and how you want to arrange them. You can put the label as well, depending on your needs you may need some other layout manager.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
 frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

to

```
 frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

and you are done

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. It just moved one JLabel that i had.

Comment: @IvanKanchev you didn't ask anything regarding a JLabel. its not my fault if you don't provide everything necessary. to get the ScrollPane displayed this is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning however by looking at this case.

I have couple of issues:

- There is issue with setting bounds of textArea
- Layout of frame/container should not be set to null.

I have removed this sentence, and I tried this code, it displays desired textArea.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/*
* Tester class
*/
public class GuiTester extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create new instance of JFrame 
    GuiTester s = new GuiTester();
    // set the frame to be visible
    s.setVisible(true);
}
/**
 * Tester constructor calling method which initialise all widgets.
 */
GuiTester() {
    //
    invokeWidget();
}

/*
 * This code is yours, just removed setting up the values of container and did that straight on the frame.
 */
void invokeWidget() {
    setBounds(100, 100, 325, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEnabled(true);
    textArea.setEditable(true);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    add(scroll);
}
```

}

This is the line that was causing issues, as well as setting layout Manager to null.

//      textArea.setBounds(10, 101, 272, 149);

I hope I helped, and if I'm wrong please correct me as well.

Comment: setBounds does not cause the code to fail. its the layoutmanager all alone. you can copy his code and just write `new BorderLayout()` instead of `null` and its working